# Can you sign a file in Powershell and validate it with an embedded crt file in a previous script?

Tags: powershell, cryptography, certificate, code-signing, signing

I found this page: https://blog.davidchristiansen.com/2016/09/howto-create-self-signed-certificates-with-powershell/ that generates a PFX file and CRT file… but I don’t see a way to use this across multiple computers portably without installing them into some cert store.

I want to be able to have a public key embedded in my first script that validates a signed second script on the network before it updates itself to the second script… which has its own validation for the third script… etc.

I want this so that someone doesn’t alter my script and I get in trouble with IT… but I don’t want to mess with computer cert stores… that might get me in trouble with IT :)

Comment: "I want this so that someone doesn’t alter my script " - if you sign a script, and the script is then modified but the signature block is still intact, integrity is considered broken and it won't execute. It must be re-signed when changes are made. This assumes the system has the appropriate execution policy configured to enforce this.

Comment: I am aware of that possibility but I think you’re missing the thrust of the question… how do I sign and verify signatures without having a public key that is installed on all computers. Also this is on a work computer that doesn’t require signed scripts so I would be using signatures to validate the file before consuming it.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: “how do I sign and verify signatures without having a public key that is installed on all computers” - you can’t really. The basic premise of authenticating signatures is that the consumer has a pre-existing store of trusted signatures that can be used to authenticate an externally supplied resource. You could sign your script with a self-signed certificate and the consumer could prove it was used to sign the script, but the consumer would have no reason to trust you as the issuer of the cert in the first place unless it’s already in a locally trusted store.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, and you have some valid points but I think you also miss my goal and need. Having the capability of having portable signatures that only need to be trusted the first time and then all successive scripts created by the original author could be trusted based on the first script. Yes… this type of behavior exists with certificate stores… but if someone doesn’t want to or can’t modify those stores there must be a way to simulate, and yes, reinvent the wheel in part in a portable manner (contained only with the scripts or files shipped with them).